# JTEMPLATE process template is undefined on pageload

Tags: jquery, jtemplate

I have a java script which i am using to pass data to a jtemplate .
but on page load the processTemplate gives me an undefined error. But when i refresh the page it is working fine.please solve this for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it. We cannot use same id for the textarea div